# How do I reference an inner class?

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I'm using Material UI styling.  it's my first time using that platform and it will be my last time.  but for now, I'm stuck with it.  so I have a question.  I have something like:

```js
.map(section => (
  <Section className={classNames(classes.section, section.class)}>
    <div className={classes.content}>
    ...
    </div>
  </Section>
))
```

where section names generally look like `Section1`, etc.  I then want to style so I'm trying this:

```js
{
  section: {},
  Section1: {
    backgroundColor: 'black',
    '& img': { ... }
    content: { border: '1px solid pink' }
  }
}
```

but the pink border is not getting applied and I can't figure out why

it appears the images get styled as expected, I see this in the generated code:

```js
.makeStyles-Section1-415 {
  content: [object Object];
}
.makeStyles-Section1-415 img {
  margin-left: 400px;
}
```

from which it's obvious that the MUI class generator doesn't know how to produce the inner class name.  obviously `'& .content'` wouldn't work either as the actual class name generated will look something like `makeStyles-content-415`

so what is the correct incantation to make this work?

p.s.

obviously I can do something heinous like:

```js
{
  Section1Content: {}
}
```

but if that's the correct answer it's a powerful reason to rip this styling system out completely

Answer (score 0):

the answer is:

```js
  Section1: {
    '& $content': { border: '1px solid pink' }
```